# TSQL: How to convert Thu Oct 17 00:00:00 GMT 2013 to date or datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

TSQL: How to convert Thu Oct 17 00:00:00 GMT 2013 to date or datetime

Comment: How is the format if the timezone is not UTC? GMT+3? GMT +3? GMT +03? GMT+3.0? +3 GMT?

Comment: It would be better to avoid this situation in the first place. Where is this string *coming from*, and why can it not perform the conversion (most languages/frameworks have richer datetime conversion functionality that T-SQL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below script.

```
DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(28)
SET @input = 'Thu Oct 17 00:00:00 GMT 2013'

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@input,' GMT',''),5,LEN(@input))as Datetime)  [DATETIME],
       CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@input,' GMT',''),5,LEN(@input))as Datetime)as DATE)  [DATE]
```

You can also use the function '`FORMAT`' to convert the input as Date.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@input,' GMT',''),5,LEN(@input)) as datetime),'yyyy-MM-dd') [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no need to convert between timezones, you could use the following TSQL:

```
DECLARE @DateText NVARCHAR(28)
SET @DateText = 'Thu Oct 17 00:00:00 GMT 2013'

SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@DateText,9,3) + SUBSTRING(@DateText,5,4) + SUBSTRING(@DateText,25,4) + SUBSTRING(@DateText,11,9), 113) "DATETIME",
        CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(@DateText,9,3) + SUBSTRING(@DateText,5,4) + SUBSTRING(@DateText,25,4), 106) "DATE"
```